# Dynamic snippet evaluation in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-snippets

Is it possible for a snippet to insert a dynamically computed completion or snippet in Visual Studio Code?

I would like a snippet for inserting date and time strings of various formats.  For example if you type `date`, the current date in ISO format would automatically be expanded.

[image: example of dynamic snippet expansion with dates]

There is a facility in Sublime Text to do this in the python API via the [`on_query_completions`](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/api.html#sublime_plugin.EventListener.on_query_completions) method in the `EventListener` class.  There the implementation would be very simple:

```py
def on_query_completions(self, view, prefix, locations):
  if prefix == 'date':
    val = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
  return [(prefix, prefix, val)] if val else []
```

I have read the documentation on [User Defined Snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/userdefinedsnippets), but it appears that one can only insert pre-defined text with tab-stops and variables that the user fills in.

If this isn't possible with the functionality exposed by the snippet API, would I be able to implement something similar with via a lower-level plugin/extension API?

I do realize that there is an existing extension called [Insert Date and Time](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jsynowiec.vscode-insertdatestring) but this works via the command pallet instead of a dynamic expansion.

Comment: You can use the [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#datetime) extension and define keyboard shortcuts

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's definitely not possible to execute a script or something similar within a snippet.

You can write an extension for Visual Studio Code instead. The extension must implement a [`CompletionItemProvider`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#CompletionItemProvider).

Its `provideCompletionItems` method would return a list of [`CompletionItems`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#CompletionItem). Their `filterText` properties would be set to the texts displayed in the suggestion box (for example "date" or "time") and their `insertText` properties would be set to the dynamically computed values.

Finally you would need to register the completion provider using `registerCompletionItemProvider`.

You should absolutely take a look on how to create an extension before you start: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-hello-world

Comment: Thanks, that pointed me in the right direction.  Using `CompletionItem`s to implement isn't quite a simple as ST for this use case, but it does afford more flexibility.

Comment: @chris-scott, I was searching for how to do the same thing (and for the same reason - timestamps in different formats). Since it sounds like you have it working, care to share your extension or put it on the VS Code Marketplace? :)

Comment: @Dullroar, yes I am planning to.  I haven't tested it outside of dev mode which is why I haven't published it yet, but I will upload to github so that you can take a look.

Comment: Looking forward to it.

Comment: is this still the case or any update on this one ? Googled but didn't found anything :(

Comment: You can execute scripts in snippets with [HyperSnips](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=draivin.hsnips) and the `insertText` can be a [dynamic constructed Snippet](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CompletionItem.insertText)

Answer (score 6):

Although, it's possible to achieve simple date-time stuff without extensions:

```
"⌚ Date Time SNIPPET": {
    "prefix": "datetime",
    "body": [
        "${CURRENT_YEAR}-${CURRENT_MONTH}-${CURRENT_DATE}T${CURRENT_HOUR}:${CURRENT_MINUTE}:${CURRENT_SECOND}",
    ]
}
```

The question is about dynamic snippets. And here's an example of using `CompletionItemProvider`:

```
const datetimeProvider = vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider(
    {
        scheme: 'file',
        // language: 'typescript',
    },
    {
        provideCompletionItems(document: vscode.TextDocument, position: vscode.Position) {
            const completionItem = new vscode.CompletionItem('datetime ⌚', vscode.CompletionItemKind.Snippet);
            completionItem.insertText = new Date(Date.now() - new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000).toISOString().split('.')[0];
            return [completionItem];
        }
    },
    // ''// trigger character
);
```