# How to add common language snippets in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: code-snippets, visual-studio-code

In official vscode documentation i have seen that is possible to create custom snippets for each language.
https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/userdefinedsnippets

Ex. `(languageId).json`

But if i want to define snippets common for all languages? It is possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Common users snippets are currently not supported, but [there is a VSCode issue tracking this feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13182). Please let us know if this is something you would find useful.

---

For completeness, [VSCode extensions can register the same snippets for multiple languages](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/extension-points#_contributessnippets) but they must explicitly specify all languages they provide snippets for (there is no `"language": "*"` option).

Comment: Matt, I'm having trouble finding exactly how to implement the 2nd part of your answer. I'm using the html boilerplate extension, here: https://github.com/sidthesloth92/vsc_html5_boilerplate and have modified the snippets section in the package.json to add another reference that specifies "php" for the language and points the same snippets file (and restarted VS Code), to no avail. Any clues?

Comment: Never mind.. I realise now that I needed to use "blade" as the language, as I had added support for that

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, global snippets are now supported in VS Code out the box.

Probably redundant information as the UI already guides you to it via the auto-generated `global.code-snippets` file when you open User Snippets in the menu.

However something I didn't know and landed on this answer looking to find is that you can also use the `scope` field to narrow global snippets to a specific subset of languages.

For example if I want a certain snippet available in both javascript and typescript, but *only* in javascript and typescript (because it's annoying if it also appears in other languages)

```
"My Snippet": {
  "prefix": "my-snippet",
  "body": [ "my snippet code..." ],
  "scope": "javascript,typescript" // define a strict subset of languages here
}
```