# CompletionProvider not showing up in VSCode Extension

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to build a VSCode extension with dynamic snippets. I have looked into this StackOverflow answer: [Dynamic snippet evaluation in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39413783/dynamic-snippet-evaluation-in-vscode) and then tried with the CompletionItemProvider (https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CompletionItemProvider) and looked into this example by Microsoft https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/completions-sample/src

Now my dynamic snippet extension calls a API (which i made and works fine) and then the data is retrieved. But the CompletionItem doesn't show up on VSCode

Here is the code for the extension

```js
const provider1 = vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('plaintext', {

        async provideCompletionItems(document: vscode.TextDocument, position: vscode.Position, token: vscode.CancellationToken, context: vscode.CompletionContext) {
            const linePrefix = document.lineAt(position).text.substr(0, position.character);

            console.log(linePrefix);

            console.log("in provide")
            
            const val = await callToAPIAndRetrieve("sa")
            console.log(val)



            // a simple completion item which inserts `Hello World!`
            const simpleCompletion = new vscode.CompletionItem(val);
            return [simpleCompletion];

        }
    },'');
context.subscriptions.push(provider1);
```

The extension is registered and all the other functionality works. Only issue is with this completion

here the variable `val` is populated with the string i want to add. My assumption is that it is something with the `async` functions. If i hardcode it, it works fine. So i suspect `async await` maybe the issue
Any help is appreciated

**EDIT**
Here is the code for `callToAPIAndRetrieve`:

```
async function callToAPIAndRetrieve(term: string): Promise<string> {
    const apiKey = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1OTU0MTI5NTQsIm5iZiI6MTU5NTQxMjk1NCwianRpIjoiY2EzOThjZDctMmEzOS00NzNjLTlmMGEtM2RjNTEyMTkwOTdiIiwiZXhwIjoxNjI2OTQ4OTU0LCJpZGVudGl0eSI6IkdldENvZGVUZXN0IiwiZnJlc2giOmZhbHNlLCJ0eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIn0.Rmjxa4zfzuGGW-DrHEasGfBJ0xZZdVmHGuDyemrrn6s";

    var url = "https://getcode.herokuapp.com/api/snippets/2";


    const response = await fetch(url,{
        method:"GET",
        headers:{
            "Authorization":"Bearer "+apiKey
        }
    });

    const json = await response.json();
    console.log(json.snippet.code)
    return (json.snippet.code)
    

}
```

**EDIT** I edited the code according to the answer and now i get these logs (which means it works) but still the problem of the completionitem not showing up is still present

```
ex
Object
sdfg
```

Here `ex` is the string i typed, `sdfg` is the code snippet to be suggested

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce with the following code and VSC 1.44

```
    const callToAPIAndRetrieve = msg => new Promise(resolve => { setTimeout(() => resolve(msg), 1000); });
    context.subscriptions.push(vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('plaintext', {
      async provideCompletionItems(document, position, token, context) {
        const val = await callToAPIAndRetrieve('Async Await!!');
        console.log(val);
        const simpleCompletion = new vscode.CompletionItem(val);
        return [simpleCompletion];
      }
    },''));
```

It shows a `Loading...` until the timer calls the `resolve` method.

---

**Edit:**

Don't assume the `fetch` will succeed.

Remove this api-key and create a new one.

```
function callToAPIAndRetrieve(term) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const apiKey = "eyJ0eX....";
    var url = "https://getcode.herokuapp.com/api/snippets/2";
    fetch(url,{
      method:"GET",
      headers:{ "Authorization":"XXX "+apiKey }
    })
    .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) { resolve(undefined); return; }
      const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type');
      if (!contentType || !contentType.includes('application/json')) { resolve(undefined); return; }
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(json => {
      if (!(json.hasOwnProperty('snippet') && json.snippet.hasOwnProperty('code'))) { resolve(undefined); return; }
      resolve(json.snippet.code);
    })
    .catch( () => resolve(undefined));
  });
}

// ...

context.subscriptions.push(vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('plaintext', {
  async provideCompletionItems(document, position, token, context) {
    const val = await callToAPIAndRetrieve('sa');
    console.log(val);
    if (!val) return undefined;
    const simpleCompletion = new vscode.CompletionItem(val);
    return [simpleCompletion];
  }
},''));
```

Comment: @CodeYard If my code also runs for you then the problem is in the `callToAPIAndRetrieve`. If you get an exception in that function it all fails

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: @CodeYard Maybe this modified `callToAPIAndRetrieve` works

Comment: Still it doesn't pop up. ```val``` is populated with the string but the completion item doesnt pop up